# How can I add 2 weeks to a date in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to add 2 weeks to date in java.

I currently use following code, it gives me today's date correctly but it gives me an error in 2 weeks date. I have attached a screenshot of the error. Any ideas on fixing this.

```
    void Days() {
    String today = LocalDate.now().toString();
    System.out.println(today);
    lbl_borrowdate.setText(today);

    //add 2 week to the current date
    LocalDate next2Week = today.plus(2, ChronoUnit.WEEKS);
    System.out.println(next2Week);
    lbl_duedate.setText(next2Week);
}
```

[image: Error]

Comment: LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
     System.out.println(today);
     //add 2 week to the current date
     LocalDate next2Week = today.plus(2, ChronoUnit.WEEKS);
     System.out.println(next2Week);

Comment: your first line of code should look like: LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

Comment: But I need to assign them to these lbl_borrowdate, lbl_duedate 
These are two labels

Comment: @gen.Strash sorry. The OP is using variables that simply don't exist. He's got bigger problems than how to use LocalDate, fundamental how to code simple variable problems.

Comment: DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd LLLL yyyy");
String formattedString = yourDateObject.format(formatter);

Comment: I manged to get this to work, thanks for your help. I'm a newbie to programming, so people like @HovercraftFullOfEels should remember that everyone is not fluent in coding. I've still got lot to learn. Anyway thanks for the help, really appreciate it.